# Why is this python Code not giving a specifc result?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I am a python beginner.

For practice, I am writing python code that would transfer data from `test1` to `test2` and then clear `test1`, as well as transfer data from `test2` to `test3`.

But when I run this code I get `test3` is empty.

```py
from sys import argv  # this argument will import argument variables
from os.path import exists
files_12 = "{} {}"
print (files_12.format(1, 2))

script, test1, test2, test3 = argv # here i get arguments

target1 = open(test1) # this opens test1 and variable set at target1
new_target = target1.read() # this reads target1 which is originally test1

print (f"Number of strings in target1 is {len(new_target)}") # in this i have given print to count number of strings in test1, why new target because i have assigned variable of new_target in read
print (f"Does the out file exist? {exists(test2)}") # this will check if if exist or not

target2 = open(test2, "w") # this will open test2
target2.write(new_target)# this will write data of test1 in test2

target3 = open(test2) # this will pen test2
veerynew = target3.read()# this will read test2

target_new = open(test1, "w") #this will open test1 in write mode which is put by "r"
target_new.truncate()# this will clead data of test1 

target4 = open(test3, "w")# this will open test3
target4.write(veerynew)#this will write data of test2 in test2

target1.close()# this will close file 1
target2.close()#this will close file 2
target3.close()#this will close file 3
target4.close()#this will close file 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these lines:

```
target2 = open(test2, "w") # this will open test2
target2.write(new_target)# this will write data of test1 in test2
target3 = open(test2) # this will pen test2
veerynew = target3.read()# this will read test2
```

your code opens `test2` for writing, writes to it, then opens it for reading without first closing it. If you close it in between:

```
target2 = open(test2, "w") # this will open test2
target2.write(new_target)# this will write data of test1 in test2
target2.close()

target3 = open(test2) # this will pen test2
veerynew = target3.read()# this will read test2
```

you will get the behaviour you expect.

Also, this line

```
print (f"Number of strings in target1 is {len(new_target)}")
```

makes it clear you are expecting a list of strings from `file.read()`, but if you look at the output you will see you get the number of bytes, not the number of strings. If you want to get a list of strings, call `file.readlines()` instead.